# retrieving .app or .exe icon and load it in pygame

Tags: python, user-interface, icons, pygame

I'm working on a custom GUI in python. I was unable to find the answer to the following question:

I don't know how to find the icon of a `.elf`, `.app`, or `.exe` file in python and get the image to Load in pygame.

Answer (score 0):

to get the .ico image of a executable on youre desktop

- right click the icon and click properties
- Then click on "Change Icon"
- this will take you to where the icons ico image file is
- then go get that .ico file and put it in the same directory of youre pygame file

then in you're pygame file use this line to make it the icon in the corner:

```
pygame.display.set_icon(icon image)
```

good luck

Comment: What about on a mac though?

Comment: on mac to change icons you have to use a program called candybar but any image will work as the icon for youre pygame

Comment: How do I get the icon of a .icns file? It's an unsupported file type.? I can get the.icns file but pygame won't load it.